# JQuery delays in changing CSS colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, pixastic

I'm having a bit of a problem with my JS code:

http://mdk.x10.mx/klab/test2.html

http://mdk.x10.mx/klab/js/bubbles.js

Right now, I am trying to get the text 'home();' to change the color of the tube on hover, which it is doing. However, I am also trying to get the color of the border and text to change along with it. The first part works without a problem, but changing the color of the element part will end up doing one of a few things:

Not activating at all
Change the color, not cycling through colors like it should
Change the color and cycle through the colors (what it should do)
Not do anything for a bit, then change the color.

Another issue I'm having is the "bubbles" won't always change colors, and the bubbles part of the script only works properly in Chrome at the moment, but this isn't my main concern for now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with JavaScript being event driven. What may happen is that the `hover` event does get fired, but the event queue is so bogged up with animation events that it's never handled or handled very late.

Comment: By event queue being bogged do you mean that I am trying to do too many things in one "cycle" of the interval? If so, is there a solution to what I'm doing that takes less to do?

Comment: The solution would be to dumb down the animations. JavaScript doesn't have threads, so it doesn't know about priorities, it's just first-come-first-serve. Before you do any of this though, please check if this really is the case. Add some console.log statements to the handler code to see when it's being executed. If those looks delayed as well you could try decreasing the number of animations or the number of 'steps' they produce (less cycles). If not, then maybe there is something else wrong.

Comment: Tried logging the console, once before changing color on the circular image, after changing it, before changing the text/border color, and after changing that. All of them occurred equally, implying to me that the script is being read. I have a strange feeling it might just be my rgb values messing up because of this